# Does the domain name has to be the same as a Route 53 Hosting Zone Name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Maybe this could sound like a dumb question, but this has been troubling me for a few days.

Let's suppose that I buy a domain in porkbun, **example.com**

And I want to manage it using an existing Hosted Zone on AWS Route 53 called **unrelated-host.org**.

As far as I know, in order to achieve this, one just have to change **example.org** NS entries to point over the `NS` entries of **unrelated-host.org**.

However, when I try to access **example.com** I'm getting no response and that's why now I'm not sure about this.

Hope somebody could give some clarification about this, regards!

Comment: you'll have to accept the fact that you need to pay $0.50 / domain for domains that aren't under the same top level domain.  As someone who has run public dns servers and now uses Route 53 instead, I'll say this is not a bad value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's suppose that I buy a domain in porkbun, example.com
>
> And I want to manage it using an existing Hosted Zone on AWS Route 53 called unrelated-host.org.

The domain names absolutely have to match. You can't configure Route53 to be the authoritative DNS server for the domain unrelated-host.org and then just expect that to magically work for the domain example.com.

> As far as I know, in order to achieve this, one just have to change example.org NS entries to point over the NS entries of unrelated-host.org.

No, that's not how DNS works at all. There are **many** customers using those same domain name servers. The domain has to match in order for those name servers to know what domain in Route53 the DNS requests are for.